# How to iterate through this and check if skip accepts numeric or not if not than print error

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const config = {
  get: {
    skip: {
      required: false,
      default: 0,
      number: true,
      in: ['query'],
      errorMessage: 'Skip is invalid',
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a bunch of these items? Why don't you just accept it like: `config.get.skip.number`?

Comment: is it the correct way of doing it ?? yes i have a bunch of items and i am new to this so i don't know how to iterate through and validate it.

Comment: If you just want to check if that `number` prop is numeric or not. For some extra safety, you can do `config?.get?.skip?.number` or with lodash `_.get(config, 'get.skip.number', false)`

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but I assume you want to do some basic type checking?

Something like this to get you in the right direction?

```js
const config = {
  get: {
    skip: {
      required: false,
      default: 0,
      type: 'number', //change this
      in: ['query'],
      errorMessage: 'Skip is invalid',
    }
  }
}

let some_value = 2;

for (let a in config){
  // a === 'get'
   for (let b in config[a]){
     // b === 'skip'
      let item = config[a][b];

      let typeof_value = typeof some_value; // 'number'
      let typeof_item = item.type;          // 'number'

      if (typeof_value !== typeof_item)
        console.error('type mismatch')
   }
}
```

Comment: So basically i have a objects of objects and inside the skip i have some key value pairs so i want to iterate through the object of objects and check if skip is accepting number or not if not than it should print the error message that skip is invalid.....